# Android MPChart Not Showing Any Dat

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to show a Horizontal Bar Graph in my Android app. I'm using MPChart library to do so.

However, I can't see graph being displayed. There is just the X axis and Y axis drawn but no actual graph.

Here's how I'm displaying it:

```
private void renderDataMPChart(ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<Integer> countList){
        

        ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<nameList.size(); i++){
            values.add(new BarEntry(countList.get(i), (float) i++));
        }


        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(values, type);
        barDataSet.setBarBorderWidth(0.9f);
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        IndexAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(nameList);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
        chart.setData(barData);
        chart.setFitBars(true);
        chart.animateXY(5000, 5000);
        chart.invalidate();
}
```

The nameList is the X Axis values and the countList contains the value to display against those name. Eg: Apple-5, Banana-10

[image: Current Graph]

Comment: Did you add axis labels?

Comment: I've used xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);